# Filling in a Bezier Curve SVG

Tags: javascript, svg

acknowledgement: [reference](https://www.particleincell.com/2012/bezier-splines/)

[SVG] How to close the path (between the 1st and the last point) and fill the area accordingly:[image]
It's not a single path, so i can't close it with 'Z' at the end

Comment: Presumably you know where the first point is so draw a line to that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's not a single path, so I can't close it with 'Z' at the end

Join the paths first.
E.g. the sample from your link is originally

```
<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="8" d="M 60 60 C 111.55555555555557 160 163.11111111111114 260 220 300"/>
<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="8" d="M 220 300 C 276.88888888888886 340 339.11111111111114 320 420 300"/>
```

But if you append the `d`string of the second to the first and replace the second `M` (Move) with `L` (LineTo), you get this:

```
<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="cyan" stroke="red" stroke-width="8" d="M 60 60 C 111.55555555555557 160 163.11111111111114 260 220 300 L 220 300 C 276.88888888888886 340 339.11111111111114 320 420 300 Z"/>
```

I have also set `fill=cyan`.[image]

Some of these drawn things are from the linked site and not in the code in my answer.